# React, not able to change/editing anything in textbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have data that I am getting from api. I am filling the data in the array. I am able to display the data properly. I am not able to make any change in the DisplayOrder Textboxes. Please find my data and code. What to do so that textbox is editable?

```
[{"featureID ":"10,"descrText":"Test1","featureText":"<h1>Feature1</h1>","displayOrder":"1},
{"featureID ":"11,"descrText":"Test2","featureText":"<h1>Feature2</h1>","displayOrder":"2},
{"featureID ":"12,"descrText":"Test3","featureText":"<h1>Feature3</h1>","displayOrder":"3}]

import React from "react";
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';
export class EditFeatures extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
              super(props);
              this.state = {
                     FeatureID: "",
                     DisplayOrder: "",
                     DescrText: "",
                     FeatureText: "",
                    Feature:[],
              };
       }
       componentDidMount() {
                     this.DisplayFeatures();
       }
       DisplayFeatures() {
              fetch(REQUEST_URL, { "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8" })
                     .then(response => response.json())
                     .then((data) => {
                           this.setState({
                                  Feature:data,
                                  loading: false
                           })
                    })
       }
       render() {
              return (
                    <div>
                           <form>
      <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellpadding="0" border="1"><tbody>
       {this.state.Feature.map((item, index) => {
              return [
           <tr key={item.FeatureID}>
                     <td width="50px">{item.featureID}
 <input type="text" name=="DisplayOrder" size="5" maxLength="10" value={item.displayOrder} 
 onChange={(ev) => this.setState({ DisplayOrder: ev.target.value })} /></td>
<td align="left"><font size="3">{ReactHtmlParser(item.descrText)}</font></td>
<td align="left">{ReactHtmlParser(item.featureText)}</td></tr>
   ];})}
</tbody></table>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Update</button>
</form>
</div>
              );
       }
}
export default EditFeatures;
```

Answer (score 1):

So when you're rendering out the value of display order, you're using the `item.displayOrder` as the inputs value; but in your `onChange` event, you're updating `this.state.DisplayOrder`. For you to be able to update the value, you would need to update `item.displayOrder` value, not the states; which would be something like

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  Feature: prevState.Feature.map(feature => {
    if (feature.featureID === IdOfFeatureYouWantToUpdate) {
      return { ...feature, { displayOrder: newValue }};
    }
  })
}));
```

If you're wanting to use the states DisplayOrder, then for the value of the input you need to use `this.state.DisplayOrder` instead of `item.displayOrder`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the same state, This might help

```
<input type="text" id={item.FeatureID} name="DisplayOrder" size="5" maxLength="10" value={item.displayOrder} 
 onChange={
    (ev) =>{
        const newFeature = this.state.Feature.map(f => {
            if (f.FeatureID == ev.target.id) {
                f.displayOrder = ev.target.value;
            } 
            return f;
        });
        this.setState({ Feature: newFeature  })
    }
 } />
```

Comment: Thanks Juan. Your solution works. If suppose Feature Array/list is empty, then how to display a message in case of empty array.